# Initializing matrix of vectors C++ with eigen

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, vector, eigen

My final goal is to have a matrix where each element is a vector using the eigen module with c++, so that I can do a summation of matrices.
The data type I came up with is:

```
Matrix<Vector3d,256,256> Matrix_A;
```

for a 256x256 matrix where each element is of data type Vector3D. This doesn't work..
Is this even possible?

Comment: If the vectors are of the same size, you can use a Tensor3D. See the relevant link from Eigen website: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read your compiler's error message you would have found something like:

```
error: static_assert failed "OBJECT_ALLOCATED_ON_STACK_IS_TOO_BIG"
```

Meaning that for such large objects you should move to a dynamically allocated matrix type:

```
int N = 256;
using Mat = Matrix<Vector3d,Dynamic,Dynamic>;
Mat A(N,N), B(N,N);
Mat C = A+B;
```

Comment: That's cool @ggael, is using `Matrix` as scalar type documented? (Which operations does it support, etc?)

Comment: It's not really documented and not very well supported, but basic manipulations and coeff-wise ops should be OK. Mixing types will likely not work. `Array` might gives you a better experience for this kind of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

[Eigen's `Matrix` template](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) takes only a scalar type for the first template parameter (whereas the doc hints that it might be possible to extend supported types, it is not clear how):

> The three mandatory template parameters of Matrix are:
>
> `Matrix<typename Scalar, int RowsAtCompileTime, int ColsAtCompileTime>`
>
> Scalar is the scalar type, i.e. the type of the coefficients. That is, if you want a matrix of floats, choose float here. See Scalar types for a list of all supported scalar types and for how to extend support to new types.

This means it is not possible to define a matrix of vectors. The only possibility I see is to use a `std::vector` of Eigen's `Matrix` objects:

```
typedef Matrix<float,256,256> my_2dfmat;

std::vector<my_2dfmat> Matrix_A(3);
```

This does have some drawbacks, such as the indexing order being non-intuitive etc.

Comment: Watch out for alignment issues when putting fixed-size matrices in std::vector https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html